# Custom filter for a field using ORM Model (result) in Kohana 3.2

Tags: php, orm, model, filter, kohana

I want to know if there's a way to filter the result from ORM.  I wish to create a custom method to my Model, for example, one to filter the output from my Data Base.  Right now, only is possible to filter the data from the POST in a form to save them into a Data Base, but, I want the opposite.

If I have one field on my table called "identification" with the value "8-985-256", I want that value as "08-0985-00256" (don't worry about how to add the extra zeros, that part is easy).

Let's say that I have a custom method on my Model called "format_identification".
Then, I get the data using the ORM class like so:

```
$user = ORM::factory('user', 1);
```

I want to echo the identification, but, with the correct format:

```
echo $user->format_identification();
```

This should print "08-0985-00256".  If I use the name of the field, that works, but, the format of the value not.

I hope you understand what I'm trying to do.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add public method to your `Model_User` file called `format_identification` like:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct access allowed.');

class Model_User extends ORM {

    public function format_identification() {

        $identification_value = $this->identification;

        // Add the extra zeros to value

        return $identification_value;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better way to solve your problem:

```
class Model_User extends ORM {

    public function __get($column) {
        if($column=='identification'){
         // Do your stuff
        }
        return parent::__get($column);
    }

}
```